# where can I find usb2can driver on linux system?

Tags: linux, driver, can-bus, cortex-m, usbserial

I've a USB to can device but I don't know how to driver it on my linux system.  The usb2can device uses Cortex M3 micro-controller(STM32F205) with internal CAN controller, which supports CAN protocols 2.0A and 2.0B , but only supply windows driver. Where can I find the similar driver to use. How to write the driver for such device?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your device support ASCII protocol, i.e. 'O', 'C' etc. commands? If yes you can use slcand from [can-utils](https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils). See this [tutorial](http://elinux.org/Bringing_CAN_interface_up#SLCAN_based_Interfaces).

Answer (score 0):

If your Linux is configured to support SocketCAN, the USB2CAN device should be supported.

Mainline Linux has supported this interface since kernel version 3.9, via the `usb_8dev` driver.

I am using both the rev.1 and rev.2 USB2CAN adapters with out of the box Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 distributions.

```
$ lsmod | egrep 'can|8dev'
Module                  Size  Used by
can_raw                20480  0
can                    24576  1 can_raw
usb_8dev               20480  0
can_dev                28672  1 usb_8dev
```